# Can I weigh my luggage at San Francisco airport for free?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, sfo

This might be a piece of cake question for people going to the airports usually.

Is there any way to weigh my luggage before going to the kiosk of the airliner to take my ticket? If so, some rough description of where or what that is would be needed, so that I can actually find the place. :)

I am willing to spend time, but not money.

Comment: You mean to go at a kiosk that is not used at the time, put over my luggage @pnuts? Is this allowed? If so, I think this would be a fantastic idea, since the counter is visible to traveller, if I recall correctly...You could post an answer, I guess! :)

Comment: Correct @pnuts and that's a good question, +1, but for someone that is willing to spend time like me, finding an idle check-in counter should be possible, so please go on and post an answer, since I would like to look it up when the time to fly comes! :)

Comment: Does it have to be at the airport? Pharmacies often have scales for weighing yourself - you could use it to weigh your suitcase.  (If it's very light, weigh yourself, then yourself holding your suitcase, and subtract.)

Comment: Yes @NateEldredge it has to be at the airport, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: hi @gsamaras - yes, it's totally normal and commonplace to just walk up to any checkin desk at all and weight your luggage.  if the check in desk is not  in use, just go ahead.  Even if it IS in use, simply say "Can I weigh this?"  Of course they will want to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On terminal 2, near the American Airlines check-in counter, there are scales available for you to use.

Comment: `scales` -> today I learn a new word! :) Can you give an intuition where would the American Airlines check-in would be? Or it is super-obvious? I will arrive with BART to the airport.

Comment: I had to research that one myself before answering :)

Comment: I see, thank you very much! I made an edit to my comment, in case you haven't noticed.. :)

Comment: @gsamaras: AA is in Terminal 2, I think.  From BART you take the AirTrain monorail to the various terminals.  So get off at Terminal 2 and follow signs to ticketing.  If your flight is from another terminal, you can go back to AirTrain and ride it to the appropriate terminal.

Comment: Terminal 2, that would be the key @NateEldredge! hooray, I would suggest you to update the answer, mentioning that AA is in Terminal 2! :)

Comment: If your flight is not from Terminal 2, then you might want to further research if there are scales in whatever terminal you are going to.  The detour to another terminal, going to and from the monorail, and waiting for it twice, would be a little inconvenient.

Comment: Nate Elredge is right, AA and the scales I mentioned are on Terminal 2. I don't know the answer about BART.

Comment: If you are concerned that you are close to the weight limit, err on the side of caution, as free scales are not calibrated like the check in counter scales.  And it is ONLY the check in counter scale being used that counts.

Comment: It would be completely madness to change terminals or whatever to weigh your bag.   Just walk up to the first and nearest checkin counter of any airline, and say "Here, I need to weigh this thanks"  it's totally, completely, S.O.P.! Enjoy!

Comment: Or if you feel antisocial, go to any closed checkin station, the scales usually are still powered on and will show the weight.