# San Francisco Airport - The plan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, airports, california, san-francisco

I am [taking BART](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79208/measuring-my-options-to-reach-the-sf-airport) to the airport this Saturday, where I fly with Air France to Paris, at 16:00, thus I will have to pass immigration.

I was [thinking to weigh my luggage before going to counters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78494/can-i-weigh-my-luggage-at-san-francisco-airport-for-free), but now I am a bit confused, since I have almost no memory of how the SF airport looks like.

Is there a way to combine a comfortable in terms of time pass from immigration *and* weigh my luggage on the scales? I mean what should be the plan I should follow? I guess it depends on the locations of the immigration check and scales.

Ideally I would like to first pass the immigration check and then weigh my luggage, since the first is critical, while the second is not, and as a fallback plan, it can be skipped.

Comment: As you leave the country you will not go through immigration as such, it works different when you leave the country.

Comment: The US has no exit immigration controls. In any event, in everyairport I've been in that has exit immigration, the checkpoint is between the check-in counters and the gates, after the security screening. So by the time you get to immigration, you no longer have your luggage.

Comment: What?? Are you sure guys? For example @phoog a guy that I asked told me that I am going to pass immigration control, in a similar manner to the one I had to overgo when I landed to SF.

Comment: nope, you will pass security, but not immigration.

Comment: But you won't clear any immigration until CDG?

Comment: Well, more importantly, do you expect your luggage to be overweight?

Comment: I have no idea what is CDG @Johns-305, and also not what you mean... :/ I have a worry about my suitcase, but I think it won't be overweight, but there is a possibility!

Comment: Charles De Gaulle airport.  But that's not really important.  Unless you expect your luggage to be overweight, you don't need to weight it in advance.

Comment: But there is a possibility that the suitcase if more than 23 kg, that's why I would like to check @Johns-305!

Comment: @gsamaras the TSA will check your identity when you enter the security screening line, but although you will show your passport there, that's not an immigration check. It's part of the security check. You also need your boarding pass there, so it happens *after* you check your bag.

Comment: @phoog when I landed on SF, I had to show my papers (I am an Intern tourist here :) ). But what you edited above is the answer I am seeking of! That edit implies that I should first weigh my luggage, then go to the counter of Air France, and eventually go passing security! I think that should be posted as an answer.. :)

Comment: And what would you do if it is?  Are you checking two bags and can distribute the weight?

Comment: @gsamaras of course there is an immigration check when you arrive. There is none when you depart.

Comment: I have a handbag, a suitcase and my laptop bag @Johns-305, I will distribute the weight, or throw some items which are not essential... :)

Comment: I would truly urge you, @gsamaras, to simply check the weight SOMEHOW! at the flat first.  SUGGESTIONS: (1) ask the neighbors! just politely knock on the door and say "Do you have a scale?"  (2) buy a luggage weigher for a few dollars (perhaps at a pharmacy? walmart or the like?) (3) when you go downstairs to get a taxi, first go to almost any pharmacy, as they almost always have a scale!.  Good luck!

Comment: @JoeBlow thank you, but I will do as planned with the airpots scales, I will be good! ;)

Comment: heh sounds great @gsamaras  !  enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're flying from USA to France, **there is no immigration on your way out**, and you will not need to pass it. Thus it can't be part of your plan.

There are scales at the check-in area where you can weight your luggage.

The layout of international terminal is typical: check-in desk, security, and gates. Air France flies from A gates. The international terminal is very small, walk to the furthest gate is probably ten minute max. A security line, however, could be long - on rare occasions took me more than an hour, although 20 minute wait is more typical.

Comment: George check my linked question, the idea, after all the help in this question is like this: 1) Go to the scales near United Airlines and do the weighting comfortably, 2) Go the Air France counter to get my ticket and 3) pass security. Does this sound feasible?

Comment: Absolutely. SFO International is a very small airport comparing to CDG or AMS, things are very close there. Since you have bags, there are no major benefits of checking in online, as there are check-in machines, and you still have to wait in line to drop your bags (although not long).

Comment: Timing-wise, there is probably 5 minute walk from United to AF checkin desks, a 3 minute walk from AF checkin to security entrance, and max 10 minute walk to your gate. You'll walk much less in SFO total than in CDG just from passport control to RER.

Comment: Instead of going a considerable distance to use the scales, I would just go to the Air France counter and check in. They will weigh your luggage at this time. If it's overweight (and they aren't willing to overlook it), then you can redistribute your belongings at this time. There's nothing really to be gained by going to the scales first (especially if you plan on going to the American Airlines scales in terminal 2 as in the linked question, as that's two terminals over), especially if you are pretty sure your bags aren't overweight.

Comment: Great approximation of the time George, exactly what I was needed. Zach, you are probably right!

Comment: @ZachLipton It might be useful for someone to weigh their luggage before they get in the check-in line, especially if it's likely to take some time to redistribute items if overweight

Comment: @Berwyn Sure, but if you think your bags probably aren't overweight and your plan to weigh the luggage involves trekking out to Terminal 2 and back, I'd just do it at check-in time (or try to find an empty counter nearby and use that to weigh).

Comment: @ZachLipton For sure there's no reason to go to another terminal to weigh your bag!

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is the same procedure in most airport, as I never been to SF.

**Check your luggage weight at home before leaving for the airport** (23 kilo max). it is annoying to have to throw stuff away or pay extra for over-weight luggage once at the airport (and not have someone with you to take back all extra stuff with them).

Once at the airport, go to the Air France check-in counter; they will also check/validate the weight of the luggage, and take them back to be put on the plane.

One that is done, you go thru security and go to your boarding gate and wait for your plane.

Comment: Max there is no mechanism of checking the luggage's weight at my Airbnb stay here in SF. I have to do the weighing in the airport...

Comment: @gsamaras then you will have to check the weight either before you check in, if you can find a scale, or by asking the check in clerk to tell you the weight as you check in.

Comment: Go to an open and unused check-in counter and ask if you can just weight your luggage; most of the time, they are happy to help, I've done it a couple of time.

Comment: As you can see in my linked question, there are scales for free too! Thanks Max, +1.